# Ejabberd Conenct with 5280 but not 5222 for external clients

Tags: docker, ejabberd, amazon-ecs

I do have ejabberd setup on my server, with hostname and SRV records in DNS but still unable to get login and register users, other side i am able to get login into admin and manage other services and nodes and virtual hosts.

I have installed in a docker. Also, I have set host name to ejabberd.yml file 
 - localhost
 - chat.example.com
I have set admin with the same host as well

Here I am able to connect the :5280/admin , but not able to connect with :5222 to use it by XMPP clients

Please let me know in case of more details required from my side.